# Queueing system in PHP

Tags: php, logic

I have a website where I have a inquiries getting assigned to sales person at help desk.The sales people are categorized in to Grade A, Grade B and Grade C with sales people with Grade A as best performer,
Grade B and Grade C as better and Fair performers.

Now when the inquiries arrive in the queue the inquiries should be assigned in the following ratio as below

```
     Grade A:Grade B:Grade C  = 3:2:1
```

That is when the queue starts first three inquiries should be assigned to Grade A, next 2 to Grade B and Last 1 to C.

How to achieve this in PHP

Edit : I have a Web form where people will be posting queries regarding various projects and it will get assigned to sales people at help desk. Based on the experience of sales people they are grouped as Grade A, Grade b and Grade C with Grade C are those who has least experience and the speed they attend the inquiries is relatively slow when compared to Grade A and Grade B

Comment: Your system is fairly complex. What have you started? What are you stuck on?

Comment: I am completely running out of logic.I used  MySQL DB to remember states of inquiries last assigned to whom

Comment: I think you need to expand your question. I can't give a meaningful answer without knowing more about the system this is going into.

Comment: Sounds like you are implementing an arbitrary priority schema based on business logic. Are you familiar with the concept of 'payload', in the context of queueing systems?

Comment: Thanks for reply Sorry Mike Purecell I am not good with concept of payload

Comment: For any meaningful responses, you will have to add more information to your question. How are you adding items to the queue? Is the queue custom or open source? And how are you accessing items within the queue?

Comment: This question is overly broad. It cannot be answered in its current form. You'll need to split the problem into smaller chunks, and ask about those.

Comment: Queue is nothing but a web form where people are posting inquiries regarding particular project.Based on how fast the sales person at the help desk can solve the inquiries for project I am assigning the incoming inquiries which I have grouped as Grade A, Grade B and Grade C.

Comment: Queue is a misnomer, and misleading in this context.

Comment: maybe you should make a flow chart of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Number the inquiries sequentially, then:

```
$inq_id = 12345;
$assign_raw = $inq_id % 6;

switch($assign_raw) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
    case 2:
        assign_to('Class_A', $inq_id);
        break;;
    case 3:
    case 4:
        assign_to('Class_B', $inq_id);
        break;;
    case 5:
        assign_to('Class_C', $inq_id);
        break;
}
```

Or perform some hash function on some [ideally unique] part of the inquiry and use that as the basis of the modulus [`%`] operation. ie:

```
$assign_raw = hexdec(substr(md5($client_email), -4)) % 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to write an algorithm which will analyze a "query" as posted by the form, and route the 'query' to the proper group. We cannot guess the business logic needed to parse the query and determine how to route the 'query', that's up to you to figure out based on your business requirements.

However, you could use the following, demonstrative ideas as a starting point:

Query 1: How do I walk and chew gum at the same time?

Solution: Parse for keywords 'walk' and 'chew', route to Group C.

Query 2: How do I create black matter?

Solution: Parse for the phrase "black matter", route to Group A.

etc.

Or if you have pre-canned queries, you could have the algorithm route to the proper group based on the submitted "query id".

This question will probably be closed b/c it will not receive an "exact" solution, however this should help get you started in the right direction.